# Insert numbers separated by commas in the same form to the same column in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to insert numbers in one form in this format
1,5,8,7.
when the submit button is clicked the odd numbers will be stored in **ODD** table and even numbers in **EVEN** table.

This the code of controller.

```
function insert_num(){
   $x=$this->input->post('number');
    foreach( explode(',',$x)as $no) {

      if ($no%2==0){
          $newdata= array(
              'number'=>$no
                );

     $this->even_num_mod->insert_even($newdata);
     redirect(base_url().'index.php/numbers/get_number');
 }
    //else if($x%2==1){
       else {
          $newdata= array('o_number'=>$no);


        $this->odd_num_mod->insert_odd($newdata);

     redirect(base_url().'index.php/numbers/get_number');
}
    }
enter code here
```

and this is the code from odd number model.

```
class Odd_num_mod extends CI_Model {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
function odd_number(){
    $sql = "select * from odd_number";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return  $query->result_array();
}

   function insert_odd($data){
  $this->db->insert('odd_number',$data);

}
```

}

and this is the code from even number model.

```
  class Even_num_mod extends CI_Model {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function even_number(){
    $sql = "select * from even_number";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();

}
function even_sum(){
     $this->db->select_sum('number');   
    $this->db->from('even_number');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return  $query->result_array();
}

function insert_even($data){
$this->db->insert('even_number',$data);

 }
```

}

and the code of the view is

```
 <table style="width: 445px; height: 40px;" border="1">
 <b>Even numbers</b>
 </br>
    <tr>
        <td> &nbsp;even numbers</td>

    </tr>
    <?php ?>
    <?php $s=0 ?>
    <?php foreach ($results as $rec) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $rec['number']?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php   $s+=$rec['number'];?>

    <?php } ?>
        <tr>
 <td><b>Sum</b</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> <?php echo $s ; ?> </td>
 </tr>



  </table>
     </br>
    </br>
</br>
```

```
<b>odd numbers</b>
</br>
    <tr>
        <td> &nbsp;odd numbers</td>

    </tr>
            <?php $d=0 ?>

    <?php foreach ($result as $res) { ?>
    <?php $y = $res['o_number'];
            if ($y %3==0){
          echo "<td bgcolor='green'>" .$res['o_number']." </td>";

   } else{
    echo "<td bgcolor='white'>".$res['o_number']." </td>" ;

   }?> 
  <?php  $res['o_number']; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php   $d+=$res['o_number'];?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
        <td> <b>Sum</b></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $d ; ?> </td>
 </tr>

 </table>
```

When the code is executed only the first number is stored in the table it belongs to.

Comment: Is this  is happening for both even and odd??

Comment: when i add odd number first like 1,2,3 the code send only 1 to odd table

Comment: when i add even number first  like 2,3,1 the code send only 2 to even table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redirecting after first insertion which will stop further execution. try this code:

**controller**

```
    function insert_num(){


       $x=$this->input->post('number');
        foreach( explode(',',$x)as $no) {

          if ($no%2==0){
              $newdata= array(
                  'number'=>$no
                    );

         $this->even_num_mod->insert_even($newdata);

     }
           else {
              $newdata= array('o_number'=>$no);


            $this->odd_num_mod->insert_odd($newdata);


    }
        }
   redirect(base_url().'index.php/numbers/get_number');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `redirect(base_url().'index.php/numbers/get_number');` from the **controller**. It will stop execution and redirect after the first number is inserted.

```
function insert_num(){
   $x=$this->input->post('number');
    foreach( explode(',',$x)as $no) {

      if ($no%2==0){
          $newdata= array(
              'number'=>$no
                );

     $this->even_num_mod->insert_even($newdata);
     //redirect(base_url().'index.php/numbers/get_number');
      }
    //else if($x%2==1){
       else {
          $newdata= array('o_number'=>$no);
          $this->odd_num_mod->insert_odd($newdata);
     //redirect(base_url().'index.php/numbers/get_number');
       }
    }
    redirect(base_url().'index.php/numbers/get_number');
```